# Speak with Animals vs augmented animal type

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Does the spell *Speak with Animals* allow communication with awakened animals that you don't share a language with?

The spell *Speak with Animals* says:

> You can comprehend and communicate 
>   with animals.

The spell *Awaken* says

> An awakened animal gets 3d6 Intelligence, +1d3 Charisma, and +2 HD. **Its 
>   type becomes magical beast (augmented animal)**.

Comment: RE: "By my understanding…" Consider editing the question to omit everything after that, and, instead, posting that as an answer.  *Really.*

Comment: In case anyone else thinks they're crazy when they read this "An awakened tree or animal can speak one language that you know, plus one additional language that you know per point of Intelligence bonus (if any).".  That doesn't invalidate the question but it made me doubt that fact.

Comment: @joedragons yeah, the specific case here the _Awaken_-er of the animal speaks no languages the PCs speak. One of the PCs is a gnome and I wouldn't be surprised if they gave _Speak with Animals_ a try.

Comment: (I'm dead serious about answering your own question, by the way. I—(or somebody else) *can* submit an answer that'll parrot your understanding if you need outside confirmation (like because the DM's demanding it), but otherwise *you* should get the rep for having figured out an (*the!*) answer yourself. So far, folks on the site are—in an incredible display of politeness—giving you the opportunity to do just that!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Fair enough. I wasn't super confident I'd gotten it right, so I was hoping to have somebody else chime in, but I'm more confident now. Will answer my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "magical beast (augmented animal)" is of type "magical beast". The "(augmented animal)" component is just there to tell you to use the features of the animal type.

*Speak with Animals* requires a target that is of the type "animal". Awakened animals are magical beasts, so it doesn't work on them.